# Why doesn't my draw function work when called on a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I'm making a client that connects to a server and sends and receives data. But when the draw function is called from the receiving thread it doesn't draw anything. Though if I call it from my button it draws correctly. Can someone help me please?

Note: It works from a button when I pass it the parameters but not from my other thread getting the receives.

- `x` is the x of where to draw
- `y` is the y of where to draw
- `b` is the block to draw

The `GetColor()` method does work — I've tested it and it draws correctly from a button but not from my receive thread.

```
public void Draw(int x, int y, int b)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x + " " + y + " " + b);
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Pen pen = new Pen(getcolor(b), 1);
    g.FillRectangle(pen.Brush, x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

i tried invoke but i think i messed up or something if someone could tell me whats wrong with this code thanks

public void Draw(int x, int y, int b)
    {

```
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Reinvoke the same method if necessary        
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { Draw(x, y, b); }));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x + " " + y + " " + b);
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(getcolor(b), 1);
        g.FillRectangle(pen.Brush, x, y, 1, 1);
    }}
```

Thanks

Comment: Some widget libraries have problems when not drawing from the main thread. Maybe try `Invoke` on the main form.

Comment: Google "Updating GUI from another thread". you will get millions of results.

Answer (score 2):

You could use InvokeRequired and Invoke to ensure that you Draw function is called by the gui thread!

Comment: Could you please give me an example? because i found several examples yet it doesn't seem to draw anyways though i can tell if it hits because the message box comes up here's my code it doesn't fit here so ill edit first post and add new code